# Does this extreme huge size determinant converge?

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, determinant, matrix-calculus

**Introduction:**

One day I calculated the value of determinant which is like Hilbert matrix $H_{n}^{p} \in \bf{R}^{\it{n \times n}}$using my computer. The determinant is defined below.

$$
\det{(H_{n}^{p})}=
\left|
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1  & {2^{p}} & {3^{p}} & \dots & {n^{p}} \\
&&&&\\
{2^{p}} & {3^{p}} & {4^{p}} & \dots & {{(n+1)}^{p}} \\
&&&&\\
{3^{p}} & {4^{p}} & {5^{p}} & \dots & {{(n+2)}^{p}} \\
&&&&\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
&&&&\\
{n^{p}} & {{(n+1)}^{p}} & {{(n+2)}^{p}} & \dots & {{(2n-1)}^{p}}
\end{array}
\right|
$$

This figure is the result of calculation. The horizontal axis is size of matrix as $n$ ,and the vertical axis is value of the determinant. The calculation range is between $p=[-2,18]$ , $n=[1,200]$, and the calculative separation is $\Delta p=0.1$.

[image]

But moreover, I want to know whether the convergence range of $p$ exists or not exactly. However I think this mere question is very difficult. So could you consider this problem when you have time?

**Problem:**

If $\det{(H_{\infty}^{p})}$ converges to a constant value, estimate the range of $p$.

Comment: I would start by looking for an expression for the eigenvalues since for symmetric matrices the determinant equals the product of eigenvalues. What is the largest eigenvalue, in absolute values, how do they decay?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer, edited to fit the newly posed problem.

The determinant of a matrix corresponds to the product of its eigenvalues. If $p=0$ the matrix is singular and so one of its eigenvalues is zero, hence the determinant exists and is zero.

If $p<-1$ then the sum of the elements on the main diagonal converges to a finite value as $n\to\infty$. This sum is called the trace. The trace equals also the sum of all eigenvalues. Hence, as $n$ increases all eigenvalues must eventually be smaller than $1$ in absolute values and therefore, their product converges to zero and so does the determinant.

Finally, I guess that we have also convergence for $p\in [-1,0]$ but that for $p>0$ the determinant diverges to infinity (maybe the Leibniz formula for a determinant can prove useful).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I glad that you have an interesting about my question. By the way, I had a mistake about the definition of determinant $\det(H^{n}_{p})$ so that I have edited the article. Thus the range of $p$ is correct as $[-2 18]$ Please see the problem again.

Comment: Ok, I edited my partial answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Some results.

If $p$ is a positive integer, then $\det(H_n^p)=0$ when $n\geq p+2$.

If $p=-1$, then we obtain the Hilbert matrix and $\log(\det(H_n^{-1}))\sim -n^2\log(4)$.

In the sequel, I work with $300$ significative digits. More generally, it seems that, for every fixed $p\in\mathbb{R}$, $\log(|\det(H_n^p)|)=O(n^2)$ and $\det(H_n^p)$ tends to $0$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$. Note that $\det(H_n^P)$ may be negative.

Although the OP does not seem to be interested by my post, I give the following example:

With $700$ digits, let $p=21.5$: $|\det(H_n^p)|$ increases until $n=29$ with $|\det(H_{29}^p)|\approx 10^{492}$. After, it decreases $|\det(H_{55}^p)|\approx 10^{27},|\det(H_{56}^p)|\approx 10^{-9}, |\det(H_{70}^p)|\approx 10^{-634}$.

Now, it's no more my business...

Comment: That is an amazing fact ! it gave a hypothesis that the value convergences to zero anyway eventually. After all, this problem is very profound.